# C# Customize Sorting in Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

[image]

is there any way that I can customize the Sorting in Data Grid View.  I wanted the column Time to be sort by "8am, 9am, 10am, 11am, 12pm, 1pm, 2pm, 3pm, 4pm".

Is that possible? Am I supposed to put it in a codeor just find it in the settings?

I saw the 'programmatic' in the Time's Sortby setting, I search in the internet but I still don't know how it works or if it will solve my problem.

Comment: Shortly: use custom comparer.

Comment: How does data get into the grid: directly or via data binding?

Comment: You probably have a data source set. Sort the data, not the control, when possible. Use a BindingSource to bind the data to a Control's DataSource.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov via data binding :)